# Small Technicality in simple Mayer Vietoris Example

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

[image]

In this example from Hatcher's book, he is trying to show how to use Mayer-Vietoris to calculate the homology groups of $S^n$.

However, I think we need $X=int(A)\cup int(B)$, which doesn't seem to hold in this example?

$int(A)\cup int(B)$ seems to be $X$ minus the "equator".

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's been a few years since I've thought about algebraic topology so I might be off, but I think you can let $A$ and $B$ overlap at the equator, so that $A\cap B$ is a strip around $S^n$ that contains $S^{n-1}$, instead of just being $S^{n-1}$ itself. Nonrigorously, you can let $A$ stretch a little south of the equator, and let $B$ stretch a little north. Then $X$ is the union of their interiors (there is some overlap now), and the strip $A\cap B$ deformation retracts onto the equator $S^{n-1}$, which is OK, since the homology groups are invariant under deformation retracts.

Comment: @BenWest Makes sense. Thanks!